# MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, flask

I am trying to use mysql to run a python-flask web application. I am connecting to the database in the main application file however, everytime I try to enter data into the database (i.e. register a customer) I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/<username>/Documents/<web application>/app.py", line 156, in register
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 94, in connection
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 81, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/<username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I have looked at similar articles with the main suggestion being:

```
(in sql)
USE mysql;
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
flush privileges;
exit;

(in terminal): sudo service mysql restart
```

How I config the database:

```
# Config MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '<root password>'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = '<db name>'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
#init MYSQL
mysql= MySQL(app)
```

However, the error still persists after trying this. I am unsure how to continue so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you can login in MySQL (directly) and execute the query, but can not via your app?

Can you provide your db config? It could be a character is parsed incorrectly.

Comment: @ikyuchukov yeah I can get into mysql and create the database and tables. And will add the config to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make the queries when logged into MySQL normally, there should be no reason to not be able to do them in the application (with the same user/pass).

I would recommend checking if your password has any characters that could parse incorrectly, eg `' \` .

If you don't see any issues with the password, you can try to just connect to MySQL from the application before doing any queries and see if the connection is successful.